# After installing paper_trail, get "irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context." from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I've tested this by running `rails c` both before and after `git stash`. On Rails 4.1 in Mavericks, after following the instructions to add the `versions` table and adding `has_paper_trail` to three models, whenever I run `rails c` I get

```
irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context.
```

I've spent some time Googling without much luck, there's old threads talking about `rspec`, but I don't see how that's relevant since I'm not using it. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: There is an open issue for this on GitHub github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/381

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed in `papertrail 4.0.0`, [here's the commit](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/commit/d048508f38f5e6acaf244869620ca7076f4e3cf7).

Answer (score 2):

RSpec used to <strike>polute</strike> provide `Object` top-level methods, e.g. `describe`, `context`, etc. Fortunately they've got rid of all the monkey patching in version 3, and now all these methods are namespaced under `RSpec`.

One can change this behaviour through the `expose_dsl_globally` [config](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/configuration/global-namespace-dsl) flag. For backwards compatibility, it defaults to true.

The warning shows up when you open the console because `paper_trail` [automatically loads](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail.rb#L134) its rspec helpers when rspec is found. And it calls `RSpec.configure` before you have the chance to tweak your own configuration.

One possible solution would be `paper_trail` to disable the automatically loading and let users to load it themselves when they see fit. However, I am not aware of the internals of the library, so I can't guarantee this wouldn't break other things.

Best!